# Lenovo ThinkServer RAID 1: Wrong Disk?

Tags: raid1, bios

For reference, please see the two attached images. Briefly, I have a Lenovo ThinkServer 440 with four SSD drives: Two 220 GB drives as RAID 1 and two 1 TB drives. The 200 GB drives were setup as RAID 1 using BIOS utilities. And the two 1 TB drives were, in Windows 10, setup as Drive E and F.

All this was fine until today where, suddenly, the computer rebooted. That maybe completed unrelated to the problem I am about to describe: In the BIOS I noted that the RAID was listed as 'Degraded'. Upon some exploring, the BIOS said that Windows will fix the RAID status.

But now the 'degraded' message is changed to 'Normal' in BIOS but drive E no longer exists (see the Disk Management image). And, from the BIOS screen cap, it looks like, somehow, the large 1 TB drive is now part of the RAID?

Basically, I am unable to access all data in Drive E because it is part of the BIOS? How do I recover the status without losing anything? These are hotswap drives in their caddies.

Thanks!

[image: BIOS]

[image: Disk Management]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I took out all hard drives and connected them, via an external USB device, to another computer. All the drives were recognized by the computer except for one of the drives in the RAID configuration.

Almost certainly the 'degraded' message meant that that drive is dead. I have removed it, backing up the system. After the backup, will remove all the drives except the good boot/RAID drive, remove the RAID--which will delete everything on that. Then will do a system restore...

I have filed an RMA with Sandisk--today was exactly one year ago I bought the drive from Amazon. Disappointed.